# DataFrame Structure concersion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
   Country              NumberA
0  France               25
1  China                30
2  US                   15
```

My goal Is to convert it to the following frame:

```
NewDf = pd.DataFrame({'France': [25],
                      'China': [30],
                      'US': [15]},
                     index=[0])
```

To do so I tried to define a function:

```
def Convert(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        NewDf = pd.DataFrame({df[df.columns[0]].iloc[i]: df[df.columns[1]].iloc[i]},
                             index=[0])
        return NewDf
```

But when I print it:

```
print(Convert(MyTestDataFrame))
```

It return only the last row:

```
              US
0             15
```

What am I doing wrong there ?

Instead of:

```
   France  China  US
0      25     30  15
```

Comment: `NewDf = pd.DataFrame({df[df.columns[0]].iloc[i] : df[df.columns[1]].iloc[i]},index=[0])`every time it loops I think it replaces afaik in python maybe im wrong

Comment: why not print everytime it loops instead of returning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
df.set_index('Country').T
```

It should give you the expected result.
If you really need to have 0 as index, add `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand this would be the solution you need.

```
import pandas as pd
NewDf = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['France','China','US'],
                   'NumberA': [25,30,15]})


col = NewDf['Country'].values.tolist()
row = NewDf['NumberA'].values.tolist()
data = {}
for x in range(0, len(col)):
    data[col[x]] = [row[x]]

NewDf2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

print("FIRST DATAFRAME:\n" + str(NewDf) + "\n\nSECOND DATAFRAME:\n" + str(NewDf2))
```